# Branch based on the WARP ID

Tags: cuda, gpu-warp

Is there any way to find the WARP id of a thread in CUDA?
I want to perform a branch based on the WARP id.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [%warpid](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#special-registers-warpid) register, and it wouldn't be hard to write a function that accesses it via inline assembly.

However, it is extremely unusual that you would ever want to use it; e.g.

- threads don't "stay put" and will change which warp they're running on over time
- it's not a globally unique identifier

which makes its possible use cases extremely limited. To quote the documentation:

> ... The warp identifier provides a unique warp number within a CTA but not across CTAs within a grid. ...
>
> Note that `%warpid` is volatile and returns the location of a thread at the moment when read, but its value may change during execution, ... `%warpid` is intended mainly to enable profiling and diagnostic code to sample and log information such as work place mapping and load distribution.

Comment: "threads don't "stay put" and will change which warp they're running on over time." Do you have a reference for that? AFAIK warp number and lane number are fixed for the life of a thread

Comment: @talonmies: Yes: the PTX ISA documentation, as quoted.

Comment: For my own purpose which is using GPGPU-Sim simulator, I am sure that the the warp id remains unchanged for the life of a thread.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yes, but that doesn't mean that "threads don't "stay put" and will change which warp they're running on over time". It means that the CTA `%warpid` value assigned to a given warp is transient. But a thread (and its 31 neighbours) stay in the same warp for their lifespan. What you didn't quote is the text directly following it which says you can use %ctaid and %tid to calculate the unique warp number.